# c++/clr IJW empty struct as an parameter function

Tags: c#, struct, c++-cli

I'm currently working on a C++ bridge between a pure C++ Api (not my code) and my Gui in C#.
I succeeded to use IJW to call native API function from C# but I'm stuck with a struct that doesn't contain anything.

The struct I need to use.

```
struct original_struct;
typedef struct original_struct *original_struct_t;
```

I must call a function with a pointer to that struct.
This function will initialize it and set a value.
Then I can use this struct pointer in another functions.

The function to initialize this struct :

```
original_create(int login, original_struct * struct);
```

An exemple of another function :

```
original_sendSomething(original_struct struct, original_settings * settings);
```

I saw somewhere that the C++ empty struct can be translated to a sByte or Byte in C#, but I'm not sure how to cast it.

How can I translate this struct to something reusable in C# (object, parameter, Intpr ?), and be sure that the value won't be destroyed ?

EDIT (Working) :

I finally succeeded, with the help of [nvoigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2060725/nvoigt)

Here is the solution to ascend to C# :

```
IntPtr ptr = IntPtr(instance_of_struct);
C#ClassHandler->PointerParameter = ptr;
```

Here is the cast from C# to c++ struct :

```
original_struct result = (original_struct)(void*)C#ClassHandler->PointerParameter;
```

I Hope it can help somebody else.

Comment: This is not formally legal, the managed layout does not have to resemble the native layout.  Using a pointer in C# is quite iffy as well, this very easily turns into a dangling pointer bug.  Don't do it, copy fields one by one or use Marshal::PtrToStructure().

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant, I suspected something like that with my version, but it worked.
Could you provide example or code, as I never succeeded to properly use Marshalling in this case. Is it related to the fact that my struct doesn't have any fields ?

Comment: I cannot guess how passing an empty struct could ever be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always store the address to something in an `IntPtr`. It's the native library's task to make sure it does not destroy the instance being pointed to. There is no garbage collection in native code.

If the `struct` does not contain anything, there is no point in having anything but an untyped pointer to it because there is no point in ever having a function in native code that takes anything but a pointer.